# Linux USERADD with -M option still creating home directory

Tags: linux

In order to automatically create domains/subdomains I need to add the user. ex.

```
useradd -gpsacln -p$1$salt1234$bTARrDtiFtJF9wDZzDFx00 -M demodelete
```

The user is added without problem.  BUT the home directory is still being created.  I won't use the home/directory for any of the site files so I prefer they are not generated automatically.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try it without the -M, according to the man page -m tells useradd to create the home directory, and there is no option for -M.  Which distro are you running?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's because you didn't quote the password field, so part of that is being interpreted as shell variables (i.e. `$1`, `$s`, `$b`), which are introducing spaces and breaking your command line.

Try quoting the value of the -p option:

```
useradd -gpsacln -p'$1$salt1234$bTARrDtiFtJF9wDZzDFx00' -M demodelete
```

Be sure to use single quotes, not double quotes, since shell variables are still interpolated within double quotes.